# Getting more predictable timing when sending txs to RPC servers

Tags: rpc, client

I noticed that there is a big variety in how long it takes between when I send my tx until it gets processed by the blockchain. Sometimes it's 1 second, othertimes it can easily be 7-8 seconds for an identical tx.

I tried different RPCs, not just the *official* one and I didn't see an improvement.

How do I get more predictable behaviour and especially how do users who are interested in MEV do it since they must be getting their tx processed within 0.100s of a second.

Answer (score 0):

Time to confirmation varies based on cluster performance. Sometimes leader nodes are totally offline, which means that you need to wait until your transaction is forwarded to a running node. Sometimes there is a lot of forking, meaning that nodes have different views of the network and need time to figure out which chain of blocks is "correct" before they can move forward and confirm the transaction. You can see mean confirmation time varies on the Solana Explorer under "Average Ping Time" at the bottom https://explorer.solana.com/

For MEV users, they typically access special clients to directly give their transactions to the leader so that they're guaranteed to include their transaction in a block. Jito is currently the only MEV client on Solana, and you can see some examples of how to create and send transaction bundles at https://github.com/jito-labs/searcher-examples/tree/master

The MEV tools, however, does not guarantee that your transaction will confirm immediately, since the cluster must still receive and process everything.